# INSERT a single row in fact table

Tags: sql, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have a requirement to perform an INSERT of new records and an UPSERT on a fact table. The fact table is f_course and the corresponding dimension table is d_course. The tables have the following columns:

```
f_course:
- id
- d_course_id
- person_number
- start_date
- end_date

d_course:
- id
- course_title
- start_date
- end_date
- hours
```

If a person signs up for more than one course on the same day, the requirement only allows us to insert one row in f_course. To clarify, for a start_date and end_date, there can only be 1 row for a person_number inserted into f_course - this row is a snapshot of courses between these dates.

Is there a way to meet this requirement and do the insert where we are only entering 1 row in f_course even if the person signs up for multiple courses on the same day?

Comment: Please update your question with enough sample source data to cover your use cases and the result you want to achieve. Also tag your question with the DBMS you are using as the SQL is probably going to be product specific

Comment: What is an `f_course` and `d_course` in english? Which one of these is a "Course" that will be inserted only once per day max? It's not clear.

Comment: provide examples